# Fatal error: Class 'Router' not found in application\third_party\datamapper\bootstrap.php

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

Please help me,

I am integrating Datamapper ORM to my CodeIgniter Application Framewarork. I have follow the all rules as mentioned in [official site](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/installation.html). But once configuring, when i run my application it throws an

> Fatal error: Class 'Router' not found in
>   application\third_party\datamapper\bootstrap.php

Comment: Which version CodeIgniter do you use, 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: I am using Codeigniter 3.x and Datamapper 1.8.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datamapper 1.8.2 is not compatible with **Codeigniter 3.x**. You should use **Codeigniter 2.x** version.